# What is the best backup/restore tools for SUSE Linux system

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse

All, Is there any tools like Norton Ghost for Linux to help backup and restore SUSE when necessary? Thanks.

Comment: Please, take a look at this thread - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41120/image-hdd-in-linux-functionality-like-norton-ghost

Comment: Wonderful , This is what am I looking for. Thank you , nwildner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Ghost4Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/)** is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

**CloneZilla...**
this is  **THE BEST** backup tool for Linux and Windows. boot with live DVD and backup to any drive. CloneZilla is linux based so no problem with reading HD partition..
http://clonezilla.org/